# Вычислить алгебраическую сумму цифр в тексте

Tags: python

Всем привет. Помогите с задачей.
Дан текст: d1-d1+d3-d4..., где d - цифра > 1. Вычислить записанную в тексте алгебраическую сумму.
Например, дана следующая строка a. Далее пытаюсь привести строку в список чисел (за исключением "+" и "-"), но дальше не могу понять, как решать.

````
a = "1+3-5+6-8+3-5+2-1+4" 
a = list(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != "+" and a[i] != "-":
        a[i] = int(a[i]) ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Проходимся по каждому символу и проверяем:

- если это + или -, то сохраняем знак, чтобы использовать его при следующей цифре
- если это цифра, то прибавляем ее к сумме, учитывая предыдущий знак

---

```
a = list("1+3-5+6-8+3-5+2-1+4")
s = 0
o = '+'

for i in a:
    if i in '+-': o = i
    else: s += int(i) * (1 if o == '+' else -1)    

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сразу засунуть строку в eval

```py
a = "1+3-5+6-8+3-5+2-1+4" 
print(eval(a))
```

P.S. eval не лучшее решение с точки зрения безопасности так как в строку можно подставить любую команду (удалить файл например) но в варианте учебного задания будем весьма оптимальным и думаю самым коротким решением задачи.

Comment: Каждый раз когда упоминается eval, нужно упомянуть его недостатки :)

Comment: `import os;os.remove("important.file.txt");1+2-3` - ой

Comment: ну да не самая оптимальная функция с точки зрения безопасности )